# Geotools minimum spanning tree

Tags: graph, minimum-spanning-tree, geotools, prims-algorithm

Is there an implementation of prim's algorithm or any other algorithm in geotools graph package for solving the minimum spanning tree problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, it is not implemented. But from a quick look at the [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) it should be possible to implement in GeoTools' [graph module](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide.old/extension/graph/index.html). Check out the code in `org.geotools.graph.traverse` and `org.geotools.graph.traverse.standard`.

If you get one working the PR's are always welcome.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Currently I am working on some other algorithms in the graph package, and I wanted it just for case. But when I have the time i'll try to implement it. So again, thanks for your answer! You saved me from hours of pointless search.